# How to match 2 files and get the required data with if loops in R?

Tags: r, join, match

I am still new to writing R scripts by myself, but this is what I want to do:

DF1:

```
Chr    Start    End    Region
chr6    3324    3360   Region1
chr4    2445    2455   Region2
chr1    1034    1090   Region4
```

DF2 (Reference):

```
Site    Chr     Location    Gene    
Site1   chr4    2447        GeneB   
Site2   chr9    1153        GeneT   
Site3   chr6    3350        GeneM   
Site4   chr1    1034        GeneC   
Site5   chr1    2000        GeneU   
Site6   chr6    3359        GeneF   
Site7   chr7    1158        GeneI   
Site8   chr4    2451        GeneO
Site9   chr6    3367        GeneZ
```

I want to annotate my DataFrame DF1 based on the reference DF2, with the following criteria.

1) Most importantly, the first rule is that the "Chr" should match with the "Chr" of the reference.

2) If it does match, then the "Location" of the "Site" in the reference DataFrame2 should be between the "Start" and "End" values of DataFrame1.

So my result in DF3 should look like this:

DF3 (Extention of DF1)

```
Chr    Start    End    Region      Site    Gene
chr6    3324    3360   Region1   Site3   GeneM
chr6    3324    3360   Region1   Site6   GeneF
chr4    2445    2455   Region2   Site1   GeneB
chr4    2445    2455   Region2   Site8   GeneO
chr1    1034    1090   Region4   Site4   GeneC
```

So Regions get additional rows depending on the number of sites that they have.

I did something as follows, but did not succeed.

```
check <- match(DF1$Chr, DF2$CHR, nomatch=0);
funtion_try <- for (i in DF2$Site) {
if (check > 0 && DF2$Location => DF1$Start && DF1$MAPINFO =< dmr$End)
DF3 <- data.frame (Chr, Start, End, DMR, Site, Gene);
write.table (DF3, file="DF3.txt", sep="\t") }
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That appears to be what would be inside a loop. You should put the whole code in here. If that is the whole code then that's at least one of the problems.

Comment: I agree.. I am still trying this in different ways, but getting a lot of errors. That is why I do not have a particular code to show. This is more or less what I am trying. Ofcourse the statement DF3 <- data.frame (Chr, Start, End, DMR, Site, Gene); should be written differently. I just want to get some hints to get this work, or if you can do a rough editing to this code below.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. This is kind of a whole code. The loop starts "for (i in DF2$Site) {"..

Comment: You are asked to not use comments to do what should be done by editing. And wouldn't you want to loop over the candidates rather than the reference table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will help,

```
dplyr::filter(merge(df1, df2, by='Chr'), Location >= Start, Location <= End)
```

With Data Table:

```
dt <- data.table(merge(df1, df2, by='Chr')) 
dt[Location >= Start & Location <= End]
```

Comment: Thanks a ton TheRimalaya. I think this should work, but the only error I see now is this "Error: incorrect length (0), expecting: 144970". Because these 2 data frames have different length of rows.

Comment: That should not bother, the merge function should deal with different number of rows

Comment: Yes, I agree, but its still showing me that error. I just googled to know that for the dplyr, the ">=" signs should be replaced by "%>%". Doing that also does not work. I am playing around a bit to work it.

Comment: if you have data.table package, you can use ´%between%´ operator.

Comment: I do have the data.table package and I just tried the %between% operator too. Still shows "Error: incorrect length (0), expecting: 144970"

Comment: Try this one with the `data.table` the solution would be, `dt <- data.table(merge(df1, df2, by='Chr')); dt[Location >= Start & Location <= End]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108716/discussion-between-pooja-mandaviya-and-therimalaya).

Comment: This works properly now. Thank you so much. May be you or someone can replace your new solution to the actual answer.

Comment: The data.table solution is quite lame really. There's a `merge.data.table` method which you fail to use.. You're just subsetting a data.table.

Comment: @Arun, Actually I could convert both df1 and df2 into `data.table` and then use the function you specified, but I was not trying to give the solution with `data.table`. I tried to give the `filter` option from `dplyr` which I suppose the same thing as i have used in `data.table`. Yes I have used the filtering method from `data.frame` which is also quite handy

Answer (score 1):

In the current devel version of data.table, `non-equi` joins are implemented. You can install it by following the instructions [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation). With that, this can be done quite efficiently as follows:

```
setDT(DF2)[DF1, .(Chr, Start, End, Region, Site, Gene), on = .(Chr, Location>=Start, Location<=End)]
#     Chr Start  End  Region  Site  Gene
# 1: chr6  3324 3360 Region1 Site3 GeneM
# 2: chr6  3324 3360 Region1 Site6 GeneF
# 3: chr4  2445 2455 Region2 Site1 GeneB
# 4: chr4  2445 2455 Region2 Site8 GeneO
# 5: chr1  1034 1090 Region4 Site4 GeneC
```

The join on `Chr` alone creates unnecessary combinations only to filter them in the next step. But *non-equi* joins looks directly for matching entries (hence the efficiency in terms of both speed and memory).